# passlib cannot be imported when using uwsgi

Tags: python, database, hash, flask-restful, passlib

I'm using flask-restful and wanted to use bcrypt from passlib to hash users passwords stored in database, when I run the solution by `python3 app.py`, everything works perfectly and I can hash the passwords and validate them , but when I run the solution through uwsgi `uwsgi uwsgi.ini` I get internal server error when I try to authenticate.

When I review the log file `from passlib.hash import bcrypt ImportError: No module named 'passlib'` , although I can import it successfully from command line as well.

I tried to do one solution suggested in :

[No module named 'passlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915448/no-module-named-passlib)

and to add "#@UnresolvedImport" to import but still didn't work.

Comment: Also I tried to use flask_bcrypt it has the same behavior as passlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After not getting any answer , I was struggling for couple of days, afterward I just deleted the virtual environment , created a new one and re-installed all required libraries "flask , flask-restful , flask_bcrypt...etc , and even uwsgi ".

Afterward I could start the application with uwsgi without getting the ImportError.